# Taskbar hidden on Windows unlock, forcing delay from resize of all Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

Sometimes (but not always), when I unlock my computer, the start bar has disappeared while locked and then upon unlock it shows back up (as it should be) which requires all windows to resize and can take a while if a lot are open.  I confirmed both autohide settings are off in the taskbar settings.  This is Windows 10 Pro version 1909.  I'm not in anything special like a full screen video app or game.

Comment: Have you enabled auto-hide taskbar setting?

Comment: @WasifHasan I confirmed it is disabled yet the taskbar still disappears when the screen is locked sometimes.  It doesn't disappear when it's unlocked.